# jQuery: links not working with jQuery enabled

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a side vertical menu, with sub pages (sub `<ul>`). I have a very nice jQuery slideToggle feature which expands the menu to show the sub pages. Though when this jQuery is targeting the menu, non of the sub page's links work. When I turn the JS off it works fine. I have been playing for the last hour or so. Any help would be appreciated.

```
// SIDE BAR MENU EXPAND

$('#left-menu ul li').click(function() {
    $(this).children("ul").slideToggle("slow");
    return false; });
```

The HTML:

```
<div id="left-menu">
                                                            <!-- first level sub-sections -->

<ul>
<li class="active"><a href=">Leather Goods &#187;</a>
   <ul>
       <li><a href="">Handbags</a></li>
       <li><a href="">Laptop &amp; Briefcase</a></li>
       <li><a href="">Pen Cases </a></li>
   </ul>
</li>

<li><a href="">Stationery</a>
    <ul>
       <li><a href="">A4</a></li>
       <li><a href="">A5</a></li>
       <li><a href="">A6</a></li>                                                                    
    </ul>
</li>
                                                                                                <li><a href="">Writing Instruments</a>
    <ul>
       <li><a href="">Accessories</a></li>
       <li><a href="">Ballpoint Pens</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
</ul>
                                                                        </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is because the `return false;` is preventing the usual link click behaviour for all your `A` tags, not just those in the headings. Try this:

HTML

```
<li class="active"><a href="" class="heading">Leather Goods &#187;</a>
   <ul>
       <li><a href="">Handbags</a></li>
       <li><a href="">Laptop &amp; Briefcase</a></li>
       <li><a href="">Pen Cases </a></li>
   </ul>
</li>
```

JS

```
$('#left-menu ul li a').click(function(e) {
    if ($(this).hasClass("heading")) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }

    $(this).next("ul").slideToggle("slow");
});
```

[**Fiddle to prove the theory**](http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/cCAMn/)

Comment: @Guy, it might also help to ensure that the link styles have `display: block;` and a value in all href attributes `href="#"`

Comment: The Href's do have URLs in them, I removed them as the site is in development and can;t really be seen yet.

Comment: Rory, thanks but this causes non of the sub menus to collapse and the links still do not work. I also tried what the other guy suggested in remving the `return false;` from the js. This made the links work, but caused the menu to collapse as soons as you clicked on a link.

Comment: @Guy You were right - there was a flaw in my logic. I've amended my answer with the correct solution, and added a fiddle so you can see it working.

Comment: This is still causing the same issue, collapsing the menu as soon as you have clicked on a link within it.

Comment: In which case the HTML you are using is different to that in your OP as you can see it works in the fiddle.

Comment: It does work sorry, had a server problem with uploading temporarily, so it wasn't updating the JS file. Thanks for your help, problem solved.

Comment: Adding event only to the top-most ul element will decrease unnecessary event binding and calls. I suggest changing `$('#left-menu ul li a').click` to `$('#left-menu > ul li a').click`

Answer (score 0):

It´s because the slideToggle() function sets the style display: block and z-index above what you are using at the moment. So just add the correct style locally to your tags or use !important in CSS.

Don´t use return false also.

Comment: So you are suggesting ammending the CSS targetting #left-menu ul li to a lower z-index?

Answer (score 0):

try change selector to `$('#left-menu > ul > li')`

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that

`$('#left-menu ul li')` is targeting all of the nested elements of type li that is nested by ul. For direct parent child relationship use `$('#left-menu > ul > li')`

Another thing you should be aware of is that events that bubble from nested items upwards, only get their default behavior (following the link in you case) if their default behavior is not prevented on the way (using jquery event.preventDefault() or by returning false) which is what you did.

So even if you select the correct elements, you need to verify you don't prevent the default behavior when the event bubbles up.

Comment: This is what I now have, it is making the links work, but now the expand/ collapse is not working. `$('#left-menu > ul > li').click(function() {
    $(this).children("ul").slideToggle("slow");
    if (!$(this).hasClass("heading"));
      
});`

Answer (score 0):

### The cause of problem

You problem is caused by the event propogation in javaScript. When you `return false` on the `ul li`, all the inside `click` event will all cancel the default behavior - which is a normal html link.

### The solution

You need to use the `event.target` to judge whether it is the link your want to stop the default behavior (in your case, it is only the a used as list heading).  I use `event.target.href === '#'` to spot this kind of anchors.  See http://jsfiddle.net/yangchenyun/9fNKD/

The html

```
<li class="active">
   <a href="#">Leather Goods &#187;</a>
   <ul>
       <li><a href="">Handbags</a></li>
       <li><a href="">Laptop &amp; Briefcase</a></li>
       <li><a href="">Pen Cases </a></li>
   </ul>
</li>
```

The js

```
$('#left-menu ul > li').click(function(event) {
    $(this).children("ul").slideToggle("slow");
    if(event.target.href === '#') return false; });
```

Comment: Getting closer, that JS works. The only thing it is doing now is collapsing the sub menu up to the link which you have clicked.

Comment: Don't you mean collapse "handbags", "laptop" and "pen cases" to "Leather Goods"?  It has already worked in this http://jsfiddle.net/yangchenyun/9fNKD/.  Pay attention, I added `<a href="#">` to every anchor in the heading `<li>`